# Adding a bottom border on hover, CSS only

Tags: html, css

How can I make a line appear only on the bottom of a linked image when hovered?

I can get an inner border to display on hover, but I only want border-bottom to display.

Here is what I have so far, even though it is with the outline property instead of border:

```
#links a img, #links a{ border: none; float: left; }
#links a{ margin: 3px; }
#links a:hover{ outline: 3px solid black; }
```

**Not hovered:**

[image]

**Hovered:**

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `#links a:hover{ border-bottom: 3px solid black; }` ?

Answer (score 15):

One option to get the same result without affecting the size of your link (borders append to the outside of the element) is to use an inset box-shadow.

Which in your example would be to change your `a:hover` to the following:

```
#links a:hover { 
    box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 0 0 cyan; 
}
```

You can see the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/kLLxkdw4/

Comment: Really nice approach to solving this problem. I used to do it with the `after` pseudo helpers, but this is much cleaner and easier

Answer (score 8):

Just assign the `border-bottom` property on `:hover`:

```
#links a:hover{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #00f; /* or whatever colour you'd prefer */
    outline: 3px solid black;
}
```

If the phrase 'anchored image' should be taken to mean the `img` is *within* the `a` element, then I'd suggest:

```
#links a:hover img {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #00f; /* or whatever you'd prefer */
}
```

Comment: I need this to work on an IMG.  This method works properly on a basic anchor tag, but I have an anchored image.  Any further ideas?

Comment: Probably, but I have no idea what your HTML is. Is your `img` *within* the `a` (and no, 'anchored image' doesn't say, or explain, that)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code I just wrote specially for you. This solution answers your question about adding a `border-bottom` on `:hover`. It even goes far beyond that and changes the `background` of the whole `#link` element on `:hover` as well with `CSS transitions`.

[A DEMO ON CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/chrisN/pen/mPvmVa)

**HTML Markup**

```
<div id="links">
  <a href="#">Example Link</a>
</div>
```

**CSS Effets & Transitions**

```
#links a{
  color:#fafafa;
  text-decoration:none;
  background-color:#8b0000;
  padding:15px;
  border-radius:5px;
  font-size:1.3em;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

}
#links a:hover{
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#002f5b;
  border-bottom:5px solid #002f5b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to work with an `img` inside your `a`, you can use a `pseudo`-element on the anchor, and then apply the border to that. Also. To avoid the border from appending to the outside of the link, you should use an inset `box-shadow` instead:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

a:hover:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -20px 0 #11c0e5;
}

a img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://oi65.tinypic.com/241jlzk.jpg"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**
    #links a:hover{ border-bottom: inset 8px #000; }

Answer (score 0):

Put your image in a div and add a mask div.

```css
#mask {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}
#mask:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid cyan;
}
#outerDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id='outerDiv'>
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/087039a00851e75ff483470e3aba89c9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" />
  <div id='mask'></div>
</div>
```