# CSS border-bottom and background on hover

Tags: html, hover, border, underline

I need to display a bottom border on mouse over.

Additionally I need to display a background color at the same time.

Now, I almost have it! If you see the example, you will see that hovering over the span will give the underline. But I need to display the underline when entering the hyperlink area.

```css
a{
text-decoration: none;
padding: 25px;

}

a:hover{
color: white;
background: blue;
}

span:hover{
border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>Combo</span></a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a bottom border on hover, CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208708/adding-a-bottom-border-on-hover-css-only)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a{
text-decoration: none;
padding: 25px;

}

a:hover{
color: white;
background: blue;
}

a:hover{
border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}


<a href="#"><span>Combo</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

**CSS**

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 25px;

}

a:hover {
    color: white;
    background: blue;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#"><span>Combo</span></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

Unfortunately, that's not exactly what I'm trying to do. 

I need the underline to appear underneath the text ( So it looks like a hyperlink )

Comment: Maybe this isn't possible with CSS? - I think we need to use JS